# (reactjs) get child component value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties

i have the following react component Timepicker:

```
export default class TimePicker extends Component{

 render(){
   return(
     <div>
      <input id={this.props.nameID} type="text"></input>
      </div>);
 }
}
```

TimePicker is used by SingleTask:

```
export default class SingleTask extends Component{
   ....
   render(){
     ....
     <TimePicker nameID="time" />
    .....
  }
}
```

How can I access the input value in TimePicker from SingleTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in 2 ways:

1. only change in SingleTask component:
   Add a ref to **TimePicker** component and access it's DOM. From there you can query your input by your choice of jQuery selector. Here I have used tag selector (Note: There is no dependency of the jQuery to be included).

:

```
export default class SingleTask extends Component{ 
  yourFunction(){
    var selectedTime = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.timePickerComp).querySelector('input').value;
   }
  render(){
     ....
     <TimePicker ref="timePickerComp" nameID="time" />
    .....
  }
}
```

2. Expose data through function of child component (The React way):

TimePicker :

```
export default class TimePicker extends Component{
function getSelectedTime(){
 return document.getElementById(this.props.nameID).value;
}
 render(){
   return(
     <div>
      <input id={this.props.nameID} type="text"></input>
      </div>);
 }
}
```

SingleTask :

```
export default class SingleTask extends Component{
   yourFunctionWhereYouNeedTime(){
    var timeSelected = this.refs.timePickerComp.getSelectedTime(); // here you'll access the child component data.
   }
   render(){
     ....
     <TimePicker ref="timePickerComp" nameID="time" />
    .....
  }
}
```